# TFS Build fails at NuGet restore

Tags: tfs, build, nuget-package-restore

I have an on-prem 2017 install of TFS.

Other similar builds work just fine however this new build i have created fails at the first step - NuGet Restore.

The path set is: ***.sln

I will add that I created the new build by copying from another (working) build. There aren't many options to set in the task so I'm not sure what went wrong.

Attached is the result from the log page.

Any help appreciated.

thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error info

`no matching files were found with search pattern: E:\vstsagent\_work\5\s\**\*.sln`

Seems the build agent is lacking of the solution file.You could double check this on the build agent folder `E:\vstsagent\_work\5\s\**` to see if there are or not.

Please go through your repository mapping settings, mark sure including and not cloaked that .sln file.

[image]